# Is "LookAt" target transform using "RotateAround" possible?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "Ball", a "Shoot Direction" and a "Center Target" in my scene. "Shoot Direction" is a child of "Ball" gameobject as shown in the image. I can rotate the "Shoot Direction" around my "Ball" using Unity's built-in "RotateAround" method.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V2iN.jpg

What I want to achieve is;

1. Rotate "Shoot Direction" around "Ball" using Unity's built-in "RotateAround" method.
2. Keep "Shoot Direction" looking at "Center Target" regarless of the position and rotation of the "Ball" at the same time.
3. Not change "Ball"s own rotation while doing number 1 and 2.

What I have so far in ShootDirection.cs attached to "Shoot Direction" gameobject:

```
    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (canRotate && rotationSpeed != 0f) {
            RotateAroundCenter ();
            LookAtCenter ();
        }
    }

    public void SetDistanceFromCenter () {
        //Set distance from the Ball's Vector3.zero
        thisTransform.localPosition = thisTransform.localPosition.normalized * distanceFromCenter;
    }

   public void LookAtCenter () {
        //Look at the Ball's Vector3.zero
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero - thisTransform.localPosition;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        thisTransform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle + 90, Vector3.forward);
    }

   public void RotateAroundCenter () {
        thisTransform.RotateAround (rotateAroundTransform.position, Vector3.back, rotationSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * rotationDirection);
   }
```

Comment: So? Does it work or do you have any issue?

Comment: All these 3 methods work. However; I need to calculate an angle in RotateAroundCenter() so that "Shoot Direction" keeps looking at "Center Target". I don't know how.

Comment: Unity has a `LookAt` method that might simplify the `LookAtCenter` method. What is the problem you are experiencing? I am interpreting the question as you are trying to keep `Shoot Direction` pointing to `Center Target` as it rotates around `Ball`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: thisTransform  ==> Shoot Direction's transform, rotateAroundTransform ==> Ball's transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a vector `distanceToBall` away from the ball and pointing at `centerTarget`:

```
public void LookAtCenter () {
    this.Transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(ball, centerTarget, -distanceToBall)
}
```

Comment: I think this only rotates Shoot Direction around its own local axis. I want Shoot Direction looking at Center Target by rotating around Ball's transform.

Comment: Ball and Shoot Direction are separate gameobjects. Shoot Direction is a child of Ball.

Comment: So you're looking for the inverse of the vector from target to ball then...

Comment: You are trying to find the fixed position in space according to where the ball is, correct? I understood the question as trying to move the shoot direction around the ball based on some player input. My mistake.

Comment: Nope, there is no player input. I want the Shoot Direction to look at Center Target by Rotating Shoot Direction around Ball. Creating another parent gameobject for Shoot Direction and setting it as a child of Ball, then using LookAt on newly created parent would solve my problem. However; I shoot the ball calculating the direction from Shoot Direction to Ball. This solution would require more modifications...

Comment: Expected behaviour: The Ball can be placed anywhere in the scene. The Shoot Direction should rotate itself around Ball so that it looks at Center Target.

Comment: Player input or no, target and ball are your independent variables (even if target is a fixed position), shoot direction is dependent, and relative to `ball`. The code is setting the world position. The localPosition will be updated to reflect the position relative to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @colin-young, I could achieve the desired result.

[Expected and achieved behaviour can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpYEi.gif)

```
    void FixedUpdate () {
        RotateTowardsTarget (LevelManager.Instance.CurrentLevel.GetPlayer ().centerTarget.transform);
        LookAtCenter ();
    }

    public void LookAtCenter () {
        //Look at the Ball's Vector3.zero
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero - thisTransform.localPosition;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        thisTransform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle + 90, Vector3.forward);
    }

    public void RotateTowardsTarget (Transform targetTransform) {
        if (targetTransform != null) {
            thisTransform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (rotateAroundTransform.position, targetTransform.position, distanceFromCenter);
        }
        LookAtCenter ();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need `LookAtCenter` at all if you use my solution (setting world position). Using a child object and trying to do things through `localPosition`, in this case, is just over-complicating things IMHO, especially when Unity will calculate that for you if you need it elsewhere. Think about when you come back to this code 6 months from now and are trying to understand what it does. Which solution is quicker to understand?

Comment: **position** is definitely a better solution than **localPosition**. LocalPosition causes unwanted behaviour when I rotate the Ball transform itself. Updated my code using **position**.

Comment: When it comes to **LookAtCenter()**; it is my bad that the method name is misleading. I use this method to rotate Shoot Direction rotate around its own axis so  so that the arrow shows the right direction. Otherwise; the arrow moves to the right position but does not show the right direction. https://i.imgur.com/aPMniUY.gif

Comment: Working on 2D and could not achieve what LookAtCenter() does with built-in LookAt method. Could use more help on that, too.

Comment: Maybe `AimAtCenter` would be a better name for your method. I don't have any 2D experience in Unity. Did you try the [Vector2.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) method?

Comment: That's a more suitable method name. Will dive into Unity docs for that method. Thanks!